# How to open a pdf file in android emulator from sdcard

Tags: android, pdf, sd-card

hi i am new to android development. i manually kept a pdf file in emulator sdcard through ddms, and i also installed "**adobe reader**" in emulator when i tried to read the pdf file in emulator 
with the following code

```
File file = 
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/iTunes Connect.pdf");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setDataAndType(path,"application/pdf");
        try 
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(xv.this, 
                getString(R.string.app_name), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

i am getting the file path is not valid error.

can any one help me in this.

Comment: does sdcard exist in your emulator?

Comment: Through adobereader i am able to see the files

Comment: okay do you have all permissions to read the path in you app manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `%20`(for white space) in between `iTunes` and `20Connect.pdf`.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/iTunes%20Connect.pdf");
```

I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

try out this path

```
File file=new File("/sdcard/iTunes Connect.pdf");
```

I think this will work for u

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use hard coded file paths. 
The framework will give you the base path of the area you want to save files to.

For SD card you should, use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

local files you should, use Context.getFilesDir() (or Context.openFileOutput(String name, int mode), etc)

local cache you should, use Context.getCacheDir()

For emulator you can try File file=new File("mnt/sdcard/iTunes Connect.pdf");

Answer (score 0):

I think that your emulator have  not adob reader install please check first it is install or not

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
    }   `enter code here`
```